# OAuth2 Silent Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, oauth-2.0, box

I'm starting to work with Box a bit... https://developers.box.com/docs/#oauth-2

I'm thinking I'm going to use Box for image (and file) hosting. I've used S3 for this task in the past, but my cohorts seem to want to use Box for some reason. So in order to use their API, you authenticate with oauth2... which involves a redirect uri... then you get a token, and you're in, right? I know how to use this to let people log in to your site, and whatnot, but I'm not sure I get how I could use it for the task at hand.

I don't want to have to log into box manually (or have any users, obviously), and I don't want to attach anything to a session to capture the auth token (one of the ways I was thinking of doing it). Is there a way to authenticate silently, with your client_id, secret, options, and authorization credentials?

Maybe I'm confused... if anyone would like to shed some knowledge on me, that'd be amazing.

This is a Rails app... tinkering with the ruby-box gem (but that's not super relevant)

Answer (score 0):

If your application is trying to manipulate a user's data, authorization from the user to your client application is definitely needed. So, you cannot do the authentication/authorization silently.

On the other hand, if your application has no intention to touch any user data and just calls Box APIs which are not associated with any user, it is possible IF Box supports "[Client Credentials Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)". Check Box API document to see whether it supports the flow or not.